# Sum of powers of primitive roots of unity as eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots-of-unity

Please help me, I don't know where to start.

Consider the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&d&e\\e&a&b&c&d\\d&e&a&b&c&\\c&d&e&a&b\\b&c&d&e&a\end{bmatrix}

with $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{C}$.

Show that the eigenvalues of this matrix are:

\begin{equation}\lambda_1 = a+b\zeta+c\zeta^2+d\zeta^3+c\zeta^4\\
\lambda_2= a+b\zeta^2+c\zeta^4+d\zeta+e\zeta^3\\
\lambda_3= a+b\zeta^3+c\zeta+d\zeta^4+e\zeta^2\\
\lambda_4=a+b\zeta^4+c\zeta^3+d\zeta^2+e\zeta\\
\lambda_5=a+b+c+d+e\\ \end{equation}

Where $\zeta$ is a fifth primitive root of 1.

Comment: You can google keyword "circulant matrix"...

Comment: Another hint:  check that the column vector with entries $(1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\zeta^3,\zeta^4)$ is an eigenvector

Comment: thank you so much